# C++ Crash on x64

Tags: c++, reflection, x86, crash, 64-bit

I have to do a little c++ reflection in my way, by creating a pointer for each property of my class(I have create a tool to help me generate corresponding c++ code), but surprise,   Building on x86 mode worked fine,  but on x64 mode it's crashed, I have no idea why! here is my code.

Product.h File

```
    class Product
    {
    public:
        int ID;
        std::string  Designation;
    };
  class Property
    {
    public:
        std::string Name;
        int Shift;
    };
    class ProductSchema
    {
    private: 
        ProductSchema();
    public: 
        static ProductSchema* Default();
        ProductSchema(const ProductSchema& other) = delete;
        Property ID;
        Property Designation;
        Property Prix;
    };
```

Product.cpp File

```
ProductSchema::ProductSchema()
{  
    Product* p = new Product(); 
    ID.Name = "ID";
    ID.Shift = (int)(int*)&p->ID - (int)p;    

    Designation.Name = "Designation";
    Designation.Shift = (int)(int*)&p->Designation - (int)p;
}
ProductSchema* ProductSchema::Default()
{
    static ProductSchema* instance_;
    if (instance_ == nullptr)
        instance_ = new ProductSchema;
    return instance_;
}
```

main.h file

```
 int main()
    {     
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Product* p = new Product();
            int* pID = (int*)((unsigned long int)p + ProductSchema::Default()->ID.Shift);
            *pID = i; // <--- error here 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Casting pointers to `int` is suspicious, you should use `std::uintptr_t`. If it doesn't work, please make a [mcve].

Comment: On an x64 system a pointer uses 64 bits, but an int is still 32.

Comment: Do not use C style casts. This is the equivalent of you telling the compiler: "I don't care how you convert this expression to the target type; just do it somehow." If you know exactly, what's happending, it may be ok, but C++ casts are preferrable, since you basically tell the reader of the code "I thought about what exactly is happening here and I'm doing it on purpose". In `(int)(int*)&p->ID` you've not only got one, but 2 reinterpret casts 1 of which can go wrong, ince pointers are 64 bit in 64 bit exes, but `int` is 32 bit.

Comment: Also this can bite you in the lower back: `static ProductSchema* instance_; if (instance_ == nullptr) instance_ = new ProductSchema;` `instance_` is not initialized, so it may or may not be null the first time you enter the function. Furthermore the object is never deallocated; preferrably let the function return a reference and don't allocate the object with `new`: `ProductSchema& ProductSchema::Default()
{
    static ProductSchema instance_;
    return instance_;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ProductSchema` class, and your `main()`, are leaking the objects they `new`.

You don't need to create an object at runtime to calculate offsets to its members, you can use [`offsetof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) at compile-time instead.

Don't use `int` or `unsigned long` to perform calculations on pointers. They are not guaranteed to be large enough. Use `(u)intptr_t` instead.

Your singleton is not initializing its `instance_` pointer before using it. It does not need to use dynamic memory at all.

Try this instead:

```
class Product
{
public:
    int ID;
    std::string Designation;
};
 
struct Property
{
    std::string Name;
    int Shift;
};

class ProductSchema
{
private: 
    ProductSchema();
public: 
    static ProductSchema& Default();
    ProductSchema(const ProductSchema& other) = delete;
    Property ID;
    Property Designation;
    Property Prix;
};
```

```
ProductSchema::ProductSchema()
{  
    ID.Name = "ID";
    ID.Shift = offsetof(Product, ID);    

    Designation.Name = "Designation";
    Designation.Shift = offsetof(Product, Designation);
}

ProductSchema& ProductSchema::Default()
{
    static ProductSchema instance_;
    return instance_;
}
```

```
int main()
{     
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        Product p;
        int* pID = reinterpret_cast<int*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&p) + ProductSchema::Default().ID.Shift);
        *pID = i;
    } 
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/2xutrC)